# Не передаются аргументы меежду фрагментами

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Пытаюсь передать аргументы с одного фрагмента в другой при нажатии на кнопку
Код нажатия на кнопку:

```
  FloatingActionButtonId_MyNoteFragment.setOnClickListener{
     /*   Bundle().apply {
            putString("theme", "")
            putString("messageText","")
            putBoolean("clickByElement",false)
        }*/
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("theme", "")
        bundle.putString("messageText","")
        bundle.putBoolean("clickByElement",false)
        val f = DetailPageNoteFragment()
        f.arguments = bundle
        replaceFragment(R.id.FrameLayoutId_MyNotes,DetailPageNoteFragment())
    }
```

Код получения атрибутов:

```
 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        theme = arguments?.getString("theme").toString()
        Log.e("456768AA",theme)
        messageText = arguments?.getString("messageText").toString()
        uidTime = arguments?.getString("uidTime").toString()
        clickByElement = arguments?.getString("clickByElement").toBoolean()

        //id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
        themeTextInputEditTextId_DetailPageNoteFragment.setText(theme)
        textTextInputEditTextId_DetailPageNoteFragment.setText(messageText)
```

В логах выводится ,что значения "theme" равно null в чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Вы же звоните Васе, и говорите ему новый пароль. А потом удивляетесь почему Петя его не знает :) Сколько раз вы DetailPageNoteFragment в первом блоке кода создаете?

Comment: В replaceFragment() нужно использовать уже созданный экземпляр фрагмента f, которому вы и передали аргументы, а не создавать новый анонимный жкземпляр

Comment: Спасибо,  понял )